# Como pegar o nome da tabela do primeiro select Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

Eu tenho a seguinte query oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA_PESSOA A WHERE A.CPF IN (SELECT B.CPF FROM TABELA_CONTA B WHERE B.CPF = A.CPF)
```

Eu quero pegar o nome da tabela do primeiro `select` que é a: *TABELA_PESSOA*.

Para isso eu coloco esse `select` acima no parâmetro do método abaixo:

```
public String obterNomePrimeiraTabela(String query) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("from\\s+\\w+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(query);       
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group().replace("from", "").trim();
    }
    return query;
}
```

O problema desse método é que se na query tiver dois select ou mais, não vai funcionar, e vai acabar indo para o ultimo `return`.

Eu só preciso pegar a tabela do primeiro select.

Comment: Por que você precisa disto ? Afinal , em tese , você escreveu o sql ? Veja isto em todo caso pode ajudar  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2075.htm#REFRN30161

Comment: Cara já está resolvido.. já me responderam em outro fórum... é só nesse que encontro dificuldade.

Comment: Aqui é um pouco chato, esta coisa de "reproduzível" é complicado em sql muitas vezes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade sua regex não funciona porque expressões regulares são *case sensitive* por padrão (diferenciam letras maiúsculas e minúsculas). Como a query possui `FROM` e a regex `from`, não é encontrada a correspondência. Uma alternativa é mudar a regex para `FROM\\s...etc`, outra é usar a *flag* [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE):

```
public String obterNomePrimeiraTabela(String query) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("from\\s+(\\w+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(query);
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group(1);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Também coloquei o trecho correspondente ao nome da tabela entre parênteses, pois isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) e eu posso recuperar somente este trecho usando `group(1)` (como é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, então é o grupo 1). Testando:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM TABELA_PESSOA A WHERE A.CPF IN (SELECT B.CPF FROM TABELA_CONTA B WHERE B.CPF = A.CPF)";
System.out.println(obterNomePrimeiraTabela(query)); // TABELA_PESSOA
```

---

## Não use regex

Mas esta solução é muito "ingênua" e propensa a falhas. Primeiro porque ela vai aceitar qualquer texto que tenha a palavra "from" seguida de qualquer coisa (ela não vai validar se a query é válida, só vai verificar se tem o texto "from" seguido de espaços, seguido de alguma coisa - ou seja, nem precisa ser uma query SQL).

Mesmo se você garante que todas as strings são queries válidas, ainda há problemas em usar a regex (o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` considera letras, números e o caractere `_`, então a regex considera que `123` e `123_` são nomes válidos). Se quer algo mais confiável, então na verdade você precisa de um *parser* de SQL.

Existem vários por aí, mas só para citar um exemplo, segue um código usando o JSqlParser, [adaptado do próprio site deles](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/example.php). Primeiro criamos uma classe que extrai as tabelas de uma query:

```
import net.sf.jsqlparser.JSQLParserException;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserManager;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.schema.Table;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.Statement;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.FromItemVisitor;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.Join;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.PlainSelect;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.Select;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.SelectVisitor;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.SubJoin;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.SubSelect;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.Union;

public class TableExtractor implements SelectVisitor, FromItemVisitor {

    private List<String> tables;

    public List<String> getTableList(Select select) {
        tables = new ArrayList<>();
        select.getSelectBody().accept(this);
        return tables;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(PlainSelect plainSelect) {
        plainSelect.getFromItem().accept(this);

        if (plainSelect.getJoins() != null) {
            for (Iterator<?> joinsIt = plainSelect.getJoins().iterator(); joinsIt.hasNext();) {
                Join join = (Join) joinsIt.next();
                join.getRightItem().accept(this);
            }
        }
    }

    public void visit(Union union) {
        for (Iterator iter = union.getPlainSelects().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            PlainSelect plainSelect = (PlainSelect) iter.next();
            visit(plainSelect);
        }
    }

    public void visit(Table tableName) {
        String tableWholeName = tableName.getWholeTableName();
        tables.add(tableWholeName);
    }

    public void visit(SubSelect subSelect) {
        subSelect.getSelectBody().accept(this);
    }

    public void visit(SubJoin subjoin) {
        subjoin.getLeft().accept(this);
        subjoin.getJoin().getRightItem().accept(this);
    }
}
```

Depois, basta usá-la:

```
public String obterNomePrimeiraTabela(String query) throws JSQLParserException {
    CCJSqlParserManager pm = new CCJSqlParserManager();
    Statement statement = pm.parse(new StringReader(query));
    if (statement instanceof Select) {
        TableExtractor tableExtractor = new TableExtractor();
        List<String> tableList = tableExtractor.getTableList((Select) statement);
        return tableList.get(0);
    }
    return query;
}

...
String query = "SELECT * FROM TABELA_PESSOA A WHERE A.CPF IN (SELECT B.CPF FROM TABELA_CONTA B WHERE B.CPF = A.CPF)";
System.out.println(obterNomePrimeiraTabela(query)); // TABELA_PESSOA
```

Pode parecer muito mais trabalhoso, mas um *parser* prevê situações que a regex não consegue, como por exemplo se tiver comentários na query:

```
query = "-- SELECT * FROM TABELA_PESSOA A \n"
        + " select coluna1, coluna2 from tabela1 t1 join tabela2 t2 on (t1.id=t2.id) WHERE A.CPF IN (SELECT B.CPF FROM TABELA_CONTA B WHERE B.CPF = A.CPF)";
```

Repare que a primeira linha está comentada, então a primeira tabela é `tabela1`, e não `TABELA_PESSOA`. Sendo assim, o *parser* retorna corretamente `tabela1`, mas a regex retorna `TABELA_PESSOA`, já que ela só está buscando qualquer coisa que esteja depois de um "FROM", sem levar em conta o contexto.

Outro caso em que a regex falha:

```
query = "SELECT date_from as data_inicial FROM TABELA_PESSOA A";
```

Como a regex busca por qualquer coisa que esteja depois de um "from", ela retorna "as" como a primeira tabela. Já o *parser* retorna corretamente `TABELA_PESSOA`.

Claro que você pode ir mudando a regex para tratar todos esses casos, mas acabará ficando tão complicada que no fim não valerá a pena. Um *parser* é bem mais garantido, já que também há a vantagem de dar erro caso a query seja inválida (fazer uma regex que verifique a sintaxe de qualquer query é extramente complicado e não vale a pena).

E há muitos outros casos a se considerar. Se for um `INSERT` com `SELECT`:

```
insert into tbl (id, nome) select id, nome from tabela_pessoa
```

O *parser* não pega o nome da tabela, pois ele entende que não é um *select statement* e sim um *insert*. Já a regex pega `tabela_pessoa`. Qual caso você quer considerar?

Enfim, depende também das queries que você está verificando, cabe a você verificar quais casos vai aceitar ou não e escolher a solução mais adequada.